# Parallel bash script looking for a password

Tags: linux, bash, passwords, cygwin

What I have is the below script for password guessing. How can I make it parallel by using command `parallel`? I know that there is no parallel in Cygwin, but I can use this script on Linux machine.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r p; do
    "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/TrueCrypt/TrueCrypt.exe" /a /s /l x /q /v container.tc /p"$p"
    code=$?
    echo "$code $p">>log.txt
    echo "$code $p"
    if [ "$code" -ne 1 ]; then echo "$p" >> found.txt ; echo -e "\\a" ; exit ; fi
done < passwds.txt
echo -e "\\a"
```

Comment: And the question is what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guese your requestion is to rewrite this scirpt using utility `parallel` in GNU/Linux.

Bulitin command `while` is read line from file `passwds.txt` line by line. If your file is large enough, then the totol consuming time will be very long.

Here, I try to use `parallel` to rewrite it

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

funcPasswdOperation(){
    p="${1:-}"
    "truecrypt" --non-interactive container.tc /p="$p"
    code=$?
    echo "$code $p">>log.txt
    echo "$code $p"
    if [ "$code" -eq 0 ]; then echo "$p" >> found.txt ; echo -e "\\a" ; exit ; fi
}

export -f funcPasswdOperation
cat passwds.txt | parallel -k -j 0 funcPasswdOperation
echo -e "\\a"
```

As I'm not test it, so I'm not guarantee this rewrited scirpt will work. But the usage method is similar.

Be careful of `open files` error.

Comment: Great script! It works! But how can I stop the job if it founds the password? `exit` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: You could consider setting a global variable, giving it a default value, then check it. If you match the correct password, change the global variable to another value, if you check the global variable has been changed, then set `exit`.